# How to get the exact coordinate of where a Tkinter widget begins and ends

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to find the exact coordinates of the following parts of widgets as shown in the image in blue circles. I cannot figure out how to do this I have tried the following:

```
self.winfo_x()
self.winfo_y()
self.winfo_xy()
```

All of these will not give the answer and I do not know any other ways after any of my research. I am making a custom way to drag widgets and I am creating a containment system and need the beginning and end points.

Image(I could not show, I don't have the reputation needed):https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID3kX.png
EDIT:
Here is the picture of my code, I implemented the answer below by using hypothetical button called s:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnIaf.png

Comment: With the commands you already found and using `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()`, what else do you need?

Comment: well when you use these, it only gives the coordinates of the widget in respect of itself so for Frame.winfo_width() would return 0 as would Frame.winfo_height(). I need the points given in respect to their place on the application not to themself

Comment: That widget doesn't look like it has width and height 0 - please share some code that creates what you shared in your screenshot, so people can better understand what you're talking about.

Comment: It depends on when you call those functions. They should show you the correct values when the layout of the window has finalized.

Comment: well wouldn't the answer stay the same no matter when it is called as long as it is placed?

Comment: No, the answer changes after the window is drawn. Until it is actually displayed, tkinter doesn't know the size or locations of windows.

Comment: so if that is called within mainloop it won't work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "within mainloop". Until the widgets are actually displayed, their position is unknowable since the act of rendering them is often what causes them to change size. Since you didn't show a proper example that we can run, it's impossible for us to know why you are getting the results you are getting.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the code directly in your question.

Comment: mainloop is the function that starts the tkinter program in which all widgets are shown and drawn and defined multiple times over to be rendered for

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `winfo_x` to get the x coordinate of the window relative to its parent. You can use `winfo.parent` to get the name of the parent window, and the method `nametowidget` to convert that to a widget. The solution is to combine those to recursively get the x or y coordinate of the widget and every parent.

It might look something like this:

```
def absolute_x(widget):
    if widget == widget.winfo_toplevel():
        # top of the widget hierarchy for this window
        return 0
    return widget.winfo_x() + absolute_x(widget.nametowidget(widget.winfo_parent()))
```

Comment: This does not work it returns 0,0

Comment: @user19926715: it sounds like you're calling it before the window is visible. The windows must be drawn before their locations can be known.

Comment: Could it be simply use `widget.master` instead of `widget.nametowidget(widget.winfo_parent())`?

Comment: Or simply `def absolute_x(widget): return widget.winfo_rootx() - widget.winfo_toplevel().winfo_rootx()`.

Comment: I tried running this I'm still getting 0,0

Comment: @user19926715: it sounds like you're not waiting for the window to be displayed. Either that, or the widgets are literally at 0,0. This method will work when used on visible widgets.